# Постоянный фон слева и справа от контента сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть макет сайта lesha.wemakesites.ru
Хочется слева и справа от самого содержания сделать постоянный фон с картинками, который останется на месте при скролле (двигается только содержание). Не могу понять, что писать в стилях wrapper или что-то такое... И можно ли это решить z-index-ом (задать приоритетность фона)?

Answer (score 0):

Можно или сделать блок с position: fixed; И поставить его по z-index ниже основного контента или использовать css свойство background-attachment для wrapper.

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись!